# Error Calling Free in windows visual c++ express

Tags: c, free, corruption

I have the following code in one cpp file which is part of a project in visual c++ 2010 I'm not understanding why the call to free fails.

```
#include <time.h>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

wchar_t * getRandomShortToken(){

    int       i;
    wchar_t * token = 0;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    token = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 6);
    memset(token, 0, sizeof(wchar_t*) *6);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        token[i] = ( rand() % 20 ) + 64;

    }

    return token;

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    wchar_t * token = 0;

    system("pause");

    token = getRandomShortToken();
    printf("My Token is '%ls'\n', token);
    system("pause");
    free(token);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the token is properly populated in the printf!

Comment: Debugging 101:  How do you know it fails?  What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?  Describe the failure in DETAIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code corrupts memory in this statement:

```
memset(token, 0, sizeof(wchar_t*) *6);
```

You probably meant:

```
memset(token, 0, sizeof(wchar_t) * 6);
```

There's a syntax error in:

```
printf("My Token is '%ls'\n', token);
```

Should be:

```
printf("My Token is '%ls'\n", token);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because token does not get null terminated and when you attempt to free it later, it tries to access memory that you did not specifically allocate.